# Estimate the curve length

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ where $g$ maps $\{z:|z|<a\}$   onto a curve $C$ with length $\Upsilon.$ I need to show that $|g'(0)|\leq \frac{\Upsilon}{2\pi a} $ 
and also to determine whether this inequality is sharp or not?
I have no clue where to start. There is no information about $g$ except that it is analytic as far as I can see. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: A non-constant analytic function can't map an open set onto a curve.

Comment: @RobertIsrael meant g  maps a circle centered at the origin with radius a into a curve

Comment: Hint: the integral of $|g'|$ over the circle is the length of the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the curve $g(a e^{i\theta})$, $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, is

$$ \Upsilon = \int_C ds = \int_0^{2\pi} a |g'(a e^{i\theta})|\; d\theta $$

If $\Gamma$ is the circle of radius $a$ centred at $0$,

$$ g'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\Gamma \dfrac{g'(z)}{z} dz  = \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} g'(ae^{i\theta})\; d\theta  $$

so $$ |g'(0)| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} |g'(ae^{i\theta})|\; d\theta
= \frac{\Upsilon}{2\pi a}$$

Try $g(z) = z$ to see that the bound is sharp.

Comment: An inequality is sharp if it can't be tightened, typically because there are examples where equality holds.